# A question about a Noetherian ring starting from a subring

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, noetherian, artinian

**Proposition.** Let $A$ be a subring of $B$, $A$ be a Noetherian, and $B$ finitely generated as an $A-$ module. Then $B$ is a Noetherian ring.

**Proof.** Since $B$ is finitely generated as an $A-$ module, then $B$ is Noetherian as an $A-$ module.

**Question** How can I conclude that $B$ is a Notherian ring? Where do we use the fact that $A$ is a sub-ring of $B$?

**Edit.**  Does this result also apply to Artinian rings?

Comment: Hi, I notice that you tend to add [meta tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags) but not subject tag. Note that meta tag are quite useless: they do not direct your post to those who are interested in ring theory for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every $B$-submodule of $B$ is an $A$-submodule, so is finitely generated over $A$, so is finitely generated over $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will add the following change to the post: does this result also apply to Artinian rings?